# How to Have Vector Inequality in Matlab's Assert?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

Code

```
NA = 1.33; 
naValues = NA+pi/180:pi/180:(NA+pi/2);
assert( (naValues > NA), 'naValues not bigger than NA');
```

where I also tried unsuccessfully `floor(sum(naValues > NA))/90` in the place of the inequality that is trying `assert( [logical], msg)`. 
Output

```
Error using assert
The condition input argument must be a scalar logical.
```

---

How can you use a vector inequality in Matlab's assert?

Comment: Use `all` or `any` to make it a scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the `naValues` to be bigger than `NA` then you can make you vector comparison a scalar (required by `assert`) using the [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html;jsessionid=a3ff9bd6490f928e30362cb81704) function like this:

```
assert(all(naValues > NA)), 'naValues not bigger than NA');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `all` or `any` , but in general I would columnize the value you pass. This way it will always be robust to matrix and N-d arrays in addition to vectors. Observe:

```
>> matrixValues = reshape(naValues,10,9)

matrixValues =

  Columns 1 through 7

          1.34745329251994          1.52198621771938          1.69651914291881          1.87105206811824          2.04558499331768          2.22011791851711          2.39465084371654
          1.36490658503989          1.53943951023932          1.71397243543875          1.88850536063819          2.06303828583762          2.23757121103705          2.41210413623648
          1.38235987755983          1.55689280275926           1.7314257279587          1.90595865315813          2.08049157835756          2.25502450355699          2.42955742875643
          1.39981317007977          1.57434609527921          1.74887902047864          1.92341194567807          2.09794487087751          2.27247779607694          2.44701072127637
          1.41726646259972          1.59179938779915          1.76633231299858          1.94086523819802          2.11539816339745          2.28993108859688          2.46446401379631
          1.43471975511966          1.60925268031909          1.78378560551853          1.95831853071796          2.13285145591739          2.30738438111682          2.48191730631626
          1.4521730476396          1.62670597283904          1.80123889803847           1.9757718232379          2.15030474843733          2.32483767363677           2.4993705988362
          1.46962634015955          1.64415926535898          1.81869219055841          1.99322511575785          2.16775804095728          2.34229096615671          2.51682389135614
          1.48707963267949          1.66161255787892          1.83614548307836          2.01067840827779          2.18521133347722          2.35974425867665          2.53427718387609
          1.50453292519943          1.67906585039887           1.8535987755983          2.02813170079773          2.20266462599716           2.3771975511966          2.55173047639603

  Columns 8 through 9

          2.56918376891597          2.74371669411541
          2.58663706143592          2.76116998663535
          2.60409035395586          2.77862327915529
           2.6215436464758          2.79607657167524
          2.63899693899575          2.81352986419518
          2.65645023151569          2.83098315671512
          2.67390352403563          2.84843644923507
          2.69135681655558          2.86588974175501
          2.70881010907552          2.88334303427495
          2.72626340159546           2.9007963267949

>> all(matrixValues)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

>> all(matrixValues(:))

ans =

     1

>>
```

Comment: Why did you particularly choose `...,10,9)`?

Comment: Assume you fix the number of elements in a column to 10. You have 777 elements. How can you choose the optimum selection of items in column here? Simple hypothesis `reshape(naValues, 10, ceil(N/10))`.

Comment: I just picked the dimensions because that's what would produce a rectangular matrix in your example. I actually wasn't suggesting a reshape as part of the solution, I was just showing my recommendation to columnize your array - by saying naValues(:) - before calling all or any because it works not only for vectors but also for matrices and multi dimensional arrays

Comment: Can you please give an example of a multidimensional array where you can use this?

Comment: `multiDimArray =  rand(2,7,11,1,2);` `numel(all(multiDimArray));` `numel(all(multiDimArray(:)))`

ans =

   154

>> 

ans =

     1

Comment: Is there any way to visualise the structure `rand(2,7,11,1,2)`?

Comment: well it is a 5 dimensional array. a matrix is 2 dimensional and makes a rectangle. a 3d matrix makes a box. those are easy to visualize. beyond that you start getting into higher dimensions and yes they are harder to visualize. perhaps 4-d can be thought of as a box that changes shape through time. 5 dimensions gets harder to think about.